# Appendind the key of a dictionary in a list if and only if all the value of that key is found in another list

Tags: python

```
L = [ ]
a ={ 'A1' : [ 'A'] }
b = { 'A' : [ 'a1', 'a2'] , 'a1' : ['a11' , 'a12'] }
c = [  'a11.txt' , 'a3.txt' ]
```

My conditions:

- If A is found in c then append A1 in L
- If a1 and a2 is found then append A in L
- If a1 is found and a2 is not found then A should not append in L
- And if for the value of key a1 if a11 is found and a12 is not found then a1 should not append in the list L and the result for this condition will be a empty list.
- And if all the values like a1, a2, a11 and a12 are found in c then key a1, A and A1 should append to the list L.

Below is my code:

```
for k,v in a.items():
    for element in v:
        if element +'.txt' in c :
            L.append(k)
        else:
            for k1,v1 in b.items():
                if element == k1:
                    for element1 in v1:
                        if element1+'.txt' in c:
                            L.append(k1)
                        else:
                            for k1,v1 in b.items():
                                if element1 == k1 :
                                    for element2 in v1 :
                                        if element2+'.txt' in c :
                                            L.append(k1)
```

My desired result should be `L = [ ]`
But I am getting `L = [ 'a1' ]`

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
a = {'A1': [ 'A']}
b = {'A': ['a1', 'a2'], 'a1': ['a11' , 'a12']}

a.update(b)

c = ['a11.txt', 'a1.txt', 'a2.txt', 'A.txt'] 
c = [x[:-4] for x in c]

L = [k for k, v in a.items() if all(x in c for x in v)]  
print(L)
# ['A1', 'A']
```

There is no need of two dictionaries. I merged them (or if you can use single at first, that would be better) and filtered `c` list to remove `'.txt'` part.

Then, we iterate through dictionary and check if all values are present in the filtered list.

Comment: In list c there is only two element i.e 'a11.txt'  and 'a3.txt' ,why are u adding extra this is fixed ,read the condition mentioned above

Comment: @Speedymastro, Replace this line `c = ['a11.txt', 'a1.txt', 'a2.txt', 'A.txt']` in the code with `c = ['a11.txt', 'a3.txt'] `, if you need answer for that. I was giving a broader example.

Comment: I think you are not getting my point what i am trying to do is that if .txt for the value of key of dictionary is present then append it's key to the list otherwise search for that value which is present as key and then search for .txt for the value of that key if .txt is present then append that key into the list L. Once see my code ,thank you for your response

Comment: @Speedymastro, You expect an empty list `[]` for `c = ['a11.txt', 'a3.txt']`, because `'a11` is in `'a1'`and also in `c` but there is no `'a12'` in `c` (So no need `'a1'` in `L`). If there were both `'a11'` and `'a12'` in `c`, you need `'a1'` in list `L`. Is that right?

Comment: @Speedymastro, in short what I understood is if there is all values for a key is available in `c` list, that key needs to be added to list `L`.

Comment: This code does that. Can you try again with your inputs?

Comment: it giving the correct result but when the b = { 'A' : [ 'a1', 'a2'] , 'a1' : ['a11' , 'a12'],'a2':['a21','a22'] } and  when c = ['a1.txt','a2.txt','a11.txt','a12.txt'] then result should be like l = ['a1','a2','A','A1']

Comment: @Speedymastro, there you go! Why do you expect that result? Can you explain? There is not even one value of `'a2'` in `c`, then why there is `'a2'` in the final list `l`? Where is `'A1'` from?

Comment: really sorry i typed wrong   b = { 'A' : [ 'a1', 'a2'] , 'a1' : ['a11' , 'a12']  'a2':['a21','a22'] }   , c = ['a11.txt' ,'a12.txt', 'a21.txt','a22.txt']  then the result should be  L = ['a1','a2','A','A1']